# How do you set the MasterType TypeName in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

If you want easy access to the MasterPage properties etc in ASP.Net you can set the MasterPage TypeName in the head of the aspx page i.e.

But How do you do this via the code file?

Answer (score 1):

TypeName is the Base class from which your Master page is going to derive so if you have defined your own BaseMaster Pag, in the code behind of the Master page inherit from your CustomMaster

instead of  System.Web.UI.MasterPage
inherit from CustomMaster

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/Site.master"; 
}
```

From: [Specifying the Master Page Programmatically (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-cs#step-2-setting-themasterpagefileproperty-from-code)